# Can we create Wifi hotspot in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have an app for connection IoT devices. So when I open the app, my wifi hotspot must be automatically enabled. Can anyone suggest a way to this?

Comment: as far as I know, this is not possible especially for ios

Comment: What about android??any luck?

Comment: Im not sure but I think its not possible as well in android

Answer (score 0):

The [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot) package is probably the best you can get with Flutter for now. Their page on pub.dev specifically states what is possible right now.